# How to convert flv video to mp3 using ffmpeg programmatically?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I need to create application on C++ for video conversion, and I can't use ffmpeg.exe.
I need to do it programmatically, but I don't know how can I do it, and I didn't find any examples on Internet.
May be somebody know something about my task? Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you just use ffmpeg.exe?  Video file conversion isn't really a trivial task, so you can expect to spend a lot of time implementing your own.  You'll also find that since FLV is a video format and MP3 is an audio format, you won't be able to convert from the former to the latter without losing the "moving picture" data.

Comment: @misha FLV is not a video format, it is a multimedia (audio/video) **container** format, even though the name means Flash Video...

Answer (score 2):

ffmpeg is an open source project. The transcoding engine used by ffmpeg is in the libraries libavcodec (for the codecs) and libavformat (for the containers). You can write your conversion as calls into these libraries, without the ffmpeg command line application.

[Here](http://www.inb.uni-luebeck.de/~boehme/using_libavcodec.html) is a tutorial on using these libraries.

Good luck.

Comment: be careful that the linked tutorial is very outdated, and the code will most probably not work with recent versions of the libav* libraries.

Comment: It's also a dead link now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another good [ffmpeg tutorial](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html).  Looking at the actual source code for ffmpeg would also help.

An updated version of the tutorial source is [here](https://github.com/mpenkov/ffmpeg-tutorial).